# Number of possible rod cuts of a long rod .

Tags: combinatorics

Basically I am trying to understand the concept of [dynamic programming via Rod Cutting example](http://www.radford.edu/~nokie/classes/360/dp-rod-cutting.html).

> How the  number of ways in which a rod of length $n$ units can be cut is ${2}^{n-1}$ and not $2^n$?

Consider the smallest cut be of one unit and there can also be a case where there is no cut at all .

Comment: There are $n-1$ potential cutting points. For each point you face a binary choice: "to cut or not to cut - that is the question".

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I see . thanks .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I take it you are only allowed to cut the rod into integer lengths. I don't know about dynamic programming, but if you mark all the places where you are allowed to cut the rod, there are $n-1$ of them, and at each of those $n-1$ places, either you cut, or you don't, making, all told, $2^{n-1}$ different ways to cut.

Comment: 'you cut, or you don't' -> so `2^(n−1)` is based probability formula or permutation/combination formula ? Sorry If my question is naive. Just want to understand this.

Comment: @vij, it's based on the multiplication formula. If you have to perform $k$ tasks, and you can perform the first task in $a_1$ different ways, and no matter how you do the first task, you can do the second task in $a_2$ different ways, and so on, and so forth, then you can do the whole job in $a_1a_2\cdots a_k$ ways.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in a dynamic programming way like this.

WAYS(n) = $1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}$WAYS(i). (this is because we can either not cut the rod (hence 1 way) or cut it by $n-i$ length and hence $i$ length remains. Now this $i$ length can be cut in WAYS(i) number of ways. And this $n-i$ length cut can go from $1$ to $n$. So we sum WAYS(i) from $i=0$ to $i=n-1$.)

WAYS(n-1) = $1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-2}$WAYS(i)..... Just by replacing n with (n-1)

Now we can subtract the second equation from first equation.

WAYS(n)-WAYS(n-1)=WAYS(n-1) $\implies$ WAYS(n)=2*WAYS(n-1)

This recurrence relation simply computes to WAYS(n)= $2^{n-1}$ with the given base condition of WAYS(1)=1.

I know this strays from the contents of this SE but since the question was put forward from a dynamic programming standpoint, I thought it was apt to show it via this method too